# How to set the "Supports Statistics" to True

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server

Just Like the Title said, I want to set the value of option "**Supports Statistics**" become "true" in the ArcGIS REST services Directory, All Layers and Tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ArcGIS Resource Center (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r3000000zr000000):

> supportsStatistics would return false in the following scenarios:
>
> - The layer / table resides in a workspace other than an ArcSDE or File Geodatabase.
> - The layer / table is a Query Layer - a layer / table that is defined by a SQL query, e.g. a layer from an enterprise database without ArcSDE (not a Geodatabase), a Geodatabase archived layer, etc.
> - The layer / table has more than one join defined on it.
> - The layer / table is joined with another layer / table from a different workspace.
> - The layer / table has an "outer" join and where the workspace is a pre-10.1 Geodatabase and application server connection is used.

You didn't provide many details about your service, but I'd guess that your layer fits one of those five scenarios.

Comment: My problem is the first scenario, I put the feature class in a *.gdb, I found the help page but I didn't read it carefully, I guess next time I should be serious about the office API Document, anyway, thanks a lot for your help